# OCR for alaska native languges

Tags: american-languages

I have a physical dictionary of a language that has very few speakers. I have scanned it and would like to OCR it as it is over 300 pages long. The problem is It has characters like ł and ŋ. I have tried multiple OCR programs but none of them work.

Comment: Which language? And, how much work are you willing to put in to customize an OCR program for this purpose?

Comment: I'd throw in on a community effort...

Comment: _ABBYY FineReader_ is OCR software that is customizable, you can simply create a new language by listing all of its letters/symbols and it will OCR texts in that language. Have you tried it? Upload a sample page or two of your scans, I'll OCR them.